# How to handle responsive and non responsive websites in one WordPress Theme?

Tags: multisite, themes, responsive

I am using [iPage hosting](https://www.ipage.com) service to display my webpage. I am using a WordPress theme called [Mantra](http://wordpress.org/themes/mantra). I want to display my website without been responsive (responsive to screen size in mobile phone). `Mantra` allowed me to disable this responsiveness at their setting. But I would like to create two separate web-pages where, if a user coming from a desktop/laptop computer display the default website, else direct them to another webpages which is responsive.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
   if (screen.width <= 699) {
   document.location = "http://example2.responsivesite.com";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Can you please tell me if this is possible. 
In another word, is it possible for me to install two WordPress theme in [Ipage](https://www.ipage.com) hosting service which can be used to maintain the same Domain name ? so that I can make one theme handle responsive websites and other one handle non responsive website. (or can this done by using one single wordpress theme)

Comment: Theoretically yes, but why do you want a user on a desktop who decreases their viewport to a mobile screen size to have a different experience than someone on a phone?  You might be better off creating a separate mobile version of the site.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want this. The reason for having a responsive design is specifically to provide optimum display on all (at least most) view ports. If you are looking to have two separate displays for mobile and desktop you might as well scrap responsiveness entirely. IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I am creating two different websites with different layout for desktop and mobile. If I make a page non responsive, the menu at the top wouldn't fit on a mobile well even thought the content I am writing bellow will fit well. Since you said this is possible, can you please tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: As for the other question. the reason I am manually writing two layouts for desktop and mobile is because in a responsive site, the content I put in there get out of order and mess up the look (when viewing through a smaller screen). such as image get out of place or it get reduce to unrecognizable size.